# How do I import an external CSS Stylesheet in fresh + preact?

Tags: typescript, jsx, deno, preact, freshjs

I tried to to use an external CSS file in my JSX code like it was detailed [here](https://reactgo.com/external-stylesheets-react/) after not finding any documentation on how to do this with preact.

This only resulted in this error.

```
Warning deno task is unstable and may drastically change in the future
Task start deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts
Watcher Process started.
The manifest has been generated for 1 routes and 1 islands.
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Expected a JavaScript or TypeScript module, but identified a Unknown module. Importing these types of modules is currently not supported.
  Specifier: file:///home/nici/Documents/deno/tiles/islands/someCssStylesheet.css
    at file:///home/nici/Documents/deno/tiles/islands/Tile.tsx:1:8
  await import(entrypoint);
  ^
    at async dev (https://deno.land/x/fresh@1.1.2/src/dev/mod.ts:187:3)
    at async file:///home/nici/Documents/deno/tiles/dev.ts:5:1
Watcher Process finished. Restarting on file change...a
```

Tile.tsx:

```js
import "./someCssStylesheet.css";

export default function Tile() {
  return (
    <div class="tile">
    </div>
  );
}
```

someCssStylesheet.css

```css
.tile {
    background-color: #1e1e2e;
    height: "500px";
    width: "500px";
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this isn't a Preact or React issue. That import is invalid JS. When working with a bundler (Webpack, Rollup, etc), one can use a loader to handle that invalid import and make sense of it (many ways to do this). Fresh, however, isn't using loaders to make sense of it. See below for the recommended path forward.

Comment: I used FreshJSS https://deno.land/x/fresh_jss . 
see one of the latest Pull Requests that includes a tiny extra documentation for the latest update.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to specifically import a stylesheet like you're attempting to *however*, if your goal is just to use an external stylesheet with deno + freshjs, you can do so by utilizing the `<Head>` component to modify the document's head and add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="someCssStylesheet.css" />`.

For example, in a completely new directory created with `deno run -A -r https://fresh.deno.dev my-project`, let's say I want the counter component to have a background color using an external stylesheet, do the following:

1. add a file `someCssStylesheet.css` to the /static folder
2. pick a route/page that you want the stylesheet to apply to i.e. `index.tsx` and open it
3. Notice the `import { Head } from "$fresh/runtime.ts";` at the top of the file. This component gives you access to the document's `<head>...</head>`. Here you add a line like `link rel="stylesheet" href="/someCssStylesheet.css" />` within the `<Head>...</Head>` component.
4. Add some styles into the sheet like:

```css
.some-class {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

5. In `Counter.tsx`, add the class to the surrounding div.

```
return (
  <div class="flex gap-2 w-full some-class">
    ...
  </div>
);
```

6. Boot it up and check it out - `deno task start`

Here's a discussion over on github from the fresh project under denoland containing a lot of the above info - [link](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/discussions/307).

Comment: I don't _think_ deno/fresh support any imports(like your question asks from `.ts` files) that aren't JS/TS modules, but I could be wrong.. https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/11961

Answer (score 1):

I may be a little bit late to this, but I was working on creating a Fresh app and ran into this problem of wanting to import a stylesheet that was only relevant to a component. There isn't a great solution to this, but I did create a plugin that allows you to define CSS per-component and apply it by adding an `inject-style` attribute to the element/component. The added advantage of this plugin is that it only ships the styles you tell it to when rendering on the server, so you don't have to ship ALL of your custom styles per page render.

You can check out the plugin [here](https://deno.land/x/fresh_inject_css)

So, in your example case, the implementation would look something like this with the plugin installed/configured:

```
// components/Tile.tsx
export default function Tile() {
  return (
    <div class="tile" inject-style="styles/tile.css">
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
/* static/styles/tile.css */
.tile {
    background-color: #1e1e2e;
    height: "500px";
    width: "500px";
}
```

Hopefully this helps anybody else that stumbles upon this problem!

**Note**: this approach does not isolate styles like CSS modules would, they are still added globally, so you should pay attention to how you scope your CSS.